# I want return duplicate node with same text value in one xml file

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Below my xml:

Filename: **relation.xml**

```
    <relations>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>01-1012946847</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 13291-2:2003</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
</relations>
```

In this xml first two nodes are same and text also same, so I want to return this with their file name as:
I want to return through xquery in marklogic server.

```
Result:
abc.xml
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
```

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code, we are not here to do your job for you because you are too lazy to try and search by yourself.

Comment: Is it correct that you are trying to iterate through all docs in your database, and want to return the name of those that contain duplicate nodes?

Comment: Actually we multiple xml files and each file having relation element. In relation element  'normativelyReferencedBy' element are coming multiple times with same text.

Comment: So we need to extract only duplicate node not distinct node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik's answer is good. However, this solution will catch cases where duplicate elements don't always precede one another:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $data :=     
<relations>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>01-1012946847</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 13291-2:2003</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
</relations>

let $map := map:map()

let $uniqueList :=
for $each at $i in $data/relation
 for $every at $j in $data/relation
   where $i ne $j
     return 
       if(fn:deep-equal($each, $every)) then
         if(fn:exists(map:get($map, xs:string($j)))) then () else map:put($map, xs:string($i), xs:string($j)) 
       else ()

return
<relations>
{
for $each at $i in $data/relation
  return 
   if(fn:exists(map:get($map, xs:string($i)))) then $each else ()
}
</relations>
```

Comment: Hi Rob,

Your code prompt following error, please check or suggest me how can I handle this.

[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Lbrace_, expecting Function30_ or Percent_

Comment: @AkbaraLI All fixed now, got messed up being pasted over somehow

Comment: Thanks, now code is proper running, still some change need to require. Above code return this:

<relations>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>01-1012946847</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 13291-2:2003</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
</relations>

Comment: But I want to return only duplicate as:

<relations>
<relation>
<normativelyReferencedBy>00-3880945351</normativelyReferencedBy>
<normativelyReferencedBy>BS EN 12899-1:2007</normativelyReferencedBy>
</relation>
</relations>

Comment: @AkbaraLI modified so it will do that. Just flip () and $each in the last if in case you decide to go back.

Answer (score 0):

By using some XSLT you could do some thing like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="//relation[preceding-sibling::relation
        [./normativelyReferencedBy/text() = current()/normativelyReferencedBy/text()]]
        ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./*"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's only intended as a boilerplate but it returns the elements that has a duplicate in front of them. You will need to add the information you want yourself.

Comment: Thanks @EriK Zander for post correct answer,  Is it possible in xquery.
Because I am using Marklogic server with Xquery. Although your answer is correct. I checked.

Comment: in marklogic you can use `xdmp:xslt-invoke` or `xdmp:xslt-eval`